# Sed to comment out a number of files

Tags: bash, shell, text, sed

I have a file with kernel configuration variables. 
I would like to comment out the last 130 lines.

I am aware that `sed` does an inline replace, how do I use this command in conjuction with `tail` to comment out the last 130 characters.

Thanks in advance.

```
tail -n 130 <file-name> | sed -i ... #I am clueless beyond this point
```

Comment: Which is it?  130 lines or 130 characters?

Answer (score 5):

to change from line 130 to end try this :

```
sed '130,$s/^/#/'
```

this add a `#` at the start of line 130 to end.

to change last 130 lines do this :

```
tac file | sed '1,130s/^/#/'  | tac
```

Comment: You can easily modify this to do the inline substitution in the file: `sed -i '130,$s/^/#/' [file]`

Comment: This is not correct if I understand it, he like to comment out the last 130 lines, not from line 130.  That's why he uses `tail`

Comment: Plus you can remove the useless file redirection; sed takes input files as arguments.

Comment: Nice use of `tac` :)  You should remove the `>` in first sed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to comment out last 130 line with `awk`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {if (i>NR-130) a[i]="#"a[i];print a[i]}}' file
```

---

Here is another shorter `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a=NR;next} FNR>a-130 {$0="#"$0}1' file{,}
```

The `file{,}` is the same as `file file`

Answer (score 1):

As i cant add a comment to طاهر answer ive had to make my own.

Your answer comments out everything from line 130 till the end.
Wasnt the question for 130 lines from the end, not 130 lines until the end ?

If it was in a script then using

```
FROM=$(wc -l < file)
(( FROM = FROM - 130 ))
```

and then

```
sed $FROM',$s/^/#/' < file
```

would work.

Comment: This is what he write: `I would like to comment out the last 130 lines` Reason for that is also shown in use of `tail`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i ':a;${s/^/#/Mg;b};N;s/\n/&/130;Ta;P;D' file1 file2 file...
```